# How can I add a comma-delimited header variable to request header with curl in Windows command line?

Tags: shell, curl, cmd

I'm trying to wrap my "header" variable into an array and add each element, individually, to the curl request header. With my current code the header is not populated and is sent with the default specs

**Header variable:** this is the text assigned to the variable to be wrapped

```
set header="Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8,X-Prototype-Version: 1.4.0,X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest,Request-Type: SOAP,Soapaction: ''"
```

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
set header=%1
set url=%2 
set payload=%3

curl -v -X POST %url% ^ --cookie request/view.txt ^
for %%i in (%header:,=" "%) do (curl -H "%%i") ^
-d %payload% 2>&1
```

**Output:**

```
>curl -v -X POST "url..." --cookie "cookiefile..." for %i in ("Content-Type: text/xml;   charset=UTF-8" "X-Prototype-Version: 1.4.0" "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" "Request-Type:  SOAP" "Soapaction: ''") do (curl -H "%i") -d "payload..."  2>&1

[10] => Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
[11] =>   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
[12] =>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
[13] => 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying  connect...
[14] => * Connected to server
[15] => > POST "url..." HTTP/1.1
[17] => > User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
[18] => > Accept: */*
[19] => > Cookie: JSESSIONID=***
[21] => > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
[22] => >
[23] => } [1313 bytes data]
[24] => < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[25] => < Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
[26] => < Cache-Control: no-store
[27] => < X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
[28] => < Server: WildFly/9
[29] => < Pragma: no-cache
[30] => < Date: Fri, 19 May 2023 17:17:14 GMT
[31] => < Connection: keep-alive
[32] => < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[33] => < Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
```

**I need the request header to be in the following format:**

[image]